# MongoClient->connected is a deprecated property

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$mongo = new MongoClient();
var_dump($mongo->connected);
```

Prints a warning: `The 'connected' property is deprecated`.

The docs say

> This property is deprecated since version 1.5.0.

What is the proper way to check if connected to Mongo?

There is already a [Jira report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-797) about changing public props to use getters `getConnected()` - but this method does not exist either. Another [Jira report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-840) mentions my propblem now, too, but it only states to update the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to do this is using [getConnections()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.getconnections.php).

This will either return an array of connections. So, to check if connected, do:

```
$mongoConnections = $mongo->getConnections()

if (false === empty($mongoConnections)) { // We are connected.
    ...
} else {                                  // Not connected
    ...
}
```

I believe that `connected` was deprecated because it would return true even if some servers had lost connection, and `getConnections()` allows you to check them atomically.

Comment: This seems to be the proper way, but it's not very obvious from the documentation.

Comment: @GolezTrol The documentation for `MongoClient` is awful. I had to read the source code to understand half of the failure returns.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see that, but now it's obvious.